# Rigging: Only one leg moves in Unity, but both legs move in Blender?

Tags: rigging, unity

I'm new to Blender and Unity, only one leg is moving correctly in Unity but in Blender both legs/armature bones move the model. One thing that did happen is the problem leg was originally not lifting and just moving forward and I had to go back and fix it, I'm thinking something happened and I don't know how to backtrack.

The missing leg is leg_R and that's the problem leg, any idea what's going on in Unity?

Playing the animation in Dope Sheets works perfectly in Blender though.

One thing I noticed, not sure if this is relevant, but under relations there's these blue squares and all bones show up in the first blue square, but the second blue square has the problem leg missing:

[image]

[image]

Comment: For clarification, those blue squares are layers and clicking on one of them moves the active selected bone to the corresponding layer. All the visible layers can be set/viewed under the Armature tab>Skeleton.

Comment: As for your problem, I can't know for sure. Try to reimport the exported model in a fresh blend file to see if they work well as intended, if they don't, it would be a problem with your export.

Comment: Okay thank you, I just started over and made sure everything was moved correctly the first time, when I went back and changed it is when I threw it off